# How to Hide a button outlet inside web service response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to hide a button outlet inside a web service response, but it is not hiding.

Note: This controller is a child view controller of a container view.

I had tried to hide the button outlet, and its working, but when I tried to hide it inside web service response it is not hiding.
Even I had also tried to hide it inside main thread.
But still no success.

Note: I am trying to hide cancel plan outlet here.

```
  [Session getLink:mainStr getPar:prStr getBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (data!= nil) {

            self->dataArray =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

            NSString *strContain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self->dataArray];

            if ([strContain isEqualToString:@"OK you can buy it"])  {

                self.cancelPlanButtonOutlet.hidden = YES;

            }else if([strContain isEqualToString:@"You have already purchased this plan."])
            {
                NSLog(@"_______Your Plan is in active state!_____________");

              //  [self.buyPlanButtonOutlet setSelected:YES];


            }

        }
```

I am getting a response and it goes inside "OK you can buy it", but the button is not hiding on completion of this.

Comment: did u check that button is connected to outlet properly?

Comment: yeah, I had mentioned above that , I am able to hide it inside viewDidLoad Method.

Comment: can you check in the response that `cancelPlanButtonOutlet` is not `nil`?

Comment: UI operation should always perform in Main Queue !!

Comment: Where are you making this service call? Are you sure your view is loaded before this service call?

Comment: @Shruti yup, I am making call to web service in ViewDidLoad

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yeah I know, I had tried it, still not useful

Comment: @hardikparmar its not nil , it is showing me reference

Comment: Have you checked the `strContain`? Is it `"OK you can buy it"`?

Comment: @hardikparmar yeah.

Comment: Try to put layoutifNeeded below that and update your view

Comment: Are you changing the visibility of this button anywhere else in your code? If yes, where does that code being called?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint after the line "self.cancelPlanButtonOutlet.hidden = YES;", then at the log, type "po self.cancelPlanButtonOutlet.hidden" to see if it has been hidden or not. If hidden is yes, and the end result you see is not hidden, it could be somewhere in the code setting it to unhide

Comment: I observe that you have use `self->dataArray` and then you can try **self->cancelPlanButtonOutlet**